# How to make Bluetooth work on Thinkpad T410?

Tags: 12.10, bluetooth, thinkpad

I'm using Ubuntu 12.10 and I have been trying to make my new keyboard (Logitech K810) and Nokia Phone 700, work with my Thinkpad T410. It just does not work. I have tried the instructions mentioned over [here](http://devasive.blogspot.co.uk/2012/11/ubuntu-1204-persistent-bluetooth-pairing.html) but it still doesn't work.

As for the phone it says that the phone is paired but then gives an error message when I try to transfer files and unexpectedly shuts down.

Any solutions? I'm desperate to make this keyboard work, and I really don't want to revert to Windows!

Answer (score 0):

Transfering files to an Ubuntu system requires the Obex demon **obexpushd** to be up and running which is not the case by default. Which is a pity because it renders bluetooth file transfer useless for most users (Ubuntu should start the demon by default - at least if there is a bluetooth device present).

As for the keyboard - I couldn't pair it either. But I manage to use it anyway by:

```
hidd --search
```

The biggest drawback is that the connectin lasts unil reboot. One has to press the pairing key on the keyboard each time. Not good. Even worse - I do not know if the connection is encrypted. So I'd rather use the onscreen keyboard for password entry (especially in sensitive environments).